# Impala on Hadoop 2.2.0 without CDH?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, impala

I want to test and configure Impala with my Hadoop 2.2.0 distribution, not Cloudera ones.

I want to know if its possible to use Impala without CDH, because I only read that Impala is CDH dependent.

I'm trying to follow the guide in Impala Github - https://github.com/cloudera/impala - and I'll do the possible changes to make it work.

Does anyone already done that? or is it really impossible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think there are two things here that should be addressed separately:

1. Running Impala on non-CDH Hadoop. It *is* possible, though it is not tested or supported by Cloudera. However, other Hadoop distributions include Impala, e.g. [MapR's distribution includes Cloudera Impala](http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Impala) and [Amazon announced support for Impala on Elastic MapReduce](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/12/12/announcing-support-for-impala-with-amazon-elastic-mapreduce/), and they have both tested that it works with their distributions. I assume you're not using MapR, either, but my point is just that it is possible.
2. Running Impala on Hadoop 2.2.0. This is also possible as the [CDH5 beta 1 release includes Hadoop 2.2.0](https://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH5/latest/CDH-Version-and-Packaging-Information/cdhvd_topic_3.html), so Impala versions 1.2 and higher should work. Please do make sure you use the latest version (1.2.3 as of now) because there are a number of important fixes in the last few minor dot releases.

So yeah, it's *possible*, though it probably won't be a smooth installation and there isn't a lot of help for this use case. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks... I'm following the guide and making changes along the way. I'll try to make a tutorial to install Impala on Hadoop 2.2.0 without CDH and publish it on my medium blog.

Comment: @BAndrade Do you have the tutorial now ? If yes can you comment with the link. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know, you should use CDH4, other versions of hadoop have the problem of compatibility.
ps: CDH3 is not available for running impala.

Comment: when you talk in compatibility, impala dont run if doesnt exists CDH4? what kind of problem of compatibility exists?

Comment: This isn't correct.  Impala does run with some very small changes.